# How to pass data from a node js file to an html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, post

In html, i am passing the value to the node js file in post form using the `form` tag.

I created a new value on the server side with the value passed in html.

I want to insert the value back into the `textbox`(result) on the html. 
And I want this process to happen on the same page.

I am writing html with the pug template engine and router name is form.

```
form(action='form' method='post')
            p.lead
                textarea(style='resize:none; width:400px; height:300px;' name='description' onkeydown="if(event.keyCode===9){var v=this.value,s=this.selectionStart,e=this.selectionEnd;this.value=v.substring(0, s)+'\t'+v.substring(e);this.selectionStart=this.selectionEnd=s+1;return false;}") #include<stdio.h>&#10;int main()&#10;{&#10;&#10;    return 0;&#10;}
            p
                input(type='text' style='resize:none; width:400px; height:50px;' name='result' readonly='readonly')
            p
                input(type='submit' value='submit' class='btn btn-success')
```

The html file is created in this way and is sending these values ​​to the server using the `post` method.

```
app.post('/form',function(req,res) {
var description = req.body.description;
var source = description.split(/\r\n|\r\n/).join("\n");

fs.writeFile(file,source,'utf8',function(error) {
    console.log('write end');
});
var compile = spawn('gcc',[file]);
compile.stdout.on('data',function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: '+data);
});
compile.stderr.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(String(data));
});
compile.on('close',function(data){
    if(data ==0) {
        var run = spawn('./a.out',[]);
        run.stdout.on('data',function(output){
            console.log('end');
        });
        run.stderr.on('data', function (output) {
        console.log(String(output));
        });
        run.on('close', function (output) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + output);
        });
        models.Code.create( {
            title: 'test1',
            code: source 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
  });
});
```

It is an excerpt from the post part of the code.

I have succeeded in compiling the value written in html `textarea` on the server side and extracting the result.

But I do not know how to send the value back to html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use express js middleware to pass a data from node.js server tk all views 
  Like this

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
res.locals.yourvariable = req.yourvariable;
next();
});
```

Hope it will be helpfull

Comment: After searching, I think it is appropriate to use ajax and I am studying that part. Thank you.