# Events handling from EJS

Tags: node.js, express, events, bootstrap-4, ejs

I am using Node.js Express.js Ejs

**Problem**

In my case i have 3 layers :

1) clients-side.js((node.js)

2) server.js(node.js)

3)front-end.ejs(ejs)

with successful form submission i emit event in *client-side.js*

> let eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
>
> eventEmitter.emit('added');

`
and i catch this event in server.js (have used express,ejs,body-parser) this is inside **app.post()** method

> eventEmitter.on('added', function(){ console.log("added successfully") });
>
> ***also***
>
> eventEmitter.on('added', addEvent);
>
> var addEvent= function () {
>
> console.log('added successfully...');
>
> `can i use some variable here and send it to ejs/html and handle it there ?`
>
> `if so how'll i know in ejs/html when i get event ?`
>
> }

here i can see the message in console

**Question**

i want to put the message after *added* event into a alert(snackbar) in **ejs/html** (uses bootstrap).

***I don't want AJAX method in ejs/html  and i don't want my 2 js to be combined, it needs to be seperate***

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more event inside this event and catch that in ejs/html and pass the value using , comma ! like this

```
eventEmitter.on('added', addEvent);
var addEvent= function () {
var yourvar ="your value";    
 eventEmitter.emit('event',yourvar);
}`
```

Comment: how'll i catch "yourvar" in html/ejs ?
can u please explain it using ejs/html ?

Comment: Using function arg like this `myEmitter.on('event', (yourvar) => {
  console.log(yourvar);
 
});`

Comment: i use node.js event module to handle events... in ejs i can't instantiate eventEmitter (myEmitter)

Comment: Pass the `eventEmitter` var to your view that is the var you store the object of the  `events.EventEmitter();` class

Comment: How to pass the var in view see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191161/how-to-pass-data-from-a-node-js-file-to-an-html-file/50191468#50191468   check the answer